# System folders not displaying properly

Tags: 16.04

I have a dual desktop setup on Ubuntu and one day a folder got extended too much (more than 2 screens on the horizontal axis).

Since then I can't open any system folder (applications still working).

Folders are displayed as you can see in the pictures and I can't get it to display properly. Tried using the hot-corners to size it on half of a screen but it is not helping.

Any suggestions of probable fixes?

[image: Opened a folder]

[image: Tried to resize it by using hotcorners]

Thank you :)

Comment: There are no pictures. What exactly do you mean by "a folder got extended too much" and "I can`t open any system folder"?

Comment: You mean you resized/ dragged a window larger than your screen? Did you have multiple monitors set up at that time? You can go into your display settings and reconfigure for a single monitor... if that's what you mean?

Comment: And I guess you caught that but the pictures didn't show up, maybe try to upload them again?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding caused by the lack of pictures :) Basically the whole GUI of any Directory is transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it’s Nautilus that’s stuck, I would start with this. Open a terminal and enter:

```
nautilus -q
```

And if that doesn’t close the window then try this one:

```
killall nautilus
```

The first command gives nautilus the chance to do some housekeeping before it exits. The second one will just terminates the application it even if it’s stuck in the middle of something which could result in data loss. Once it closes, you should be able to re-launch normally.

Comment: Tried both. Restarted a few times but the error is persistent

Comment: I think that i have found the problem if you look at the second picture you can see that there is a file with a very long name. 4eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee....Problem is that i dont know how to remove that from there cuz I can`t find it in my terminal